# My replace function has issues

Tags: emacs, replace, elisp

I a trying to make a simple replace method as a new Lisp user, but cannot understand why this isn't working correctly.

```
;replace element e1 with element e2 in a list L
(defun my-replace (e1 e2 L)
  (cond
   ;if the first of L is e1, cons e2 & rest L 
   ((equal (car L) (e1)) (cons (e2) (my-replace (e1 e2 (cdr L)))))
   ;else cons e1 & rest L
   (t  (cons (e1) (my-replace (e1 e2 (cdr L)))))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. First, you have a few extra parentheses. `e1` means the value of `e1`, but `(e1)` means the return value of the function `e1`. As you have no such function, it will fail.

Additionally, your loop lacks the terminate condition. As it is now, with the first issue fixed, it will run indefinitely, always taking the second branch and recursively calling itself with `nil` as `L`.

And finally, the first argument to `cons` in the latter branch is wrong: When `(car L)` does not match `e1`, you want to construct the result from `(car L)` and not `e1`, right? That is preserve what was in the list, and not replace it with the first argument.

Here's the fixed version:

```
(defun my-replace (e1 e2 L)
  (cond
    ;;if at the end of list, terminate
    ((null L) nil)
    ;;if the first of L is e1, cons e2 & rest L 
    ((equal (car L) e1)
     (cons e2 (my-replace e1 e2 (cdr L))))
    ;;else cons e1 & rest L
    (t
     (cons (car L) (my-replace e1 e2 (cdr L))))))
```